# implement DP for a recursive function

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have the following recursive function:

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;

ull calc(ull b, ull e)
{
  if (!b) return e;
  if (!e) return b;
  return calc(b - 1, e - 1) + calc(b - 1, e) - calc(b, e - 1);
}
```

I want to implement it with dynamic programming (i.e. using storage). I have tried to use a `map<pair<ull, ull>, ull>` but it is too slow also. I couldn't implement it using arrays `O(1)` too.

I want to find a solution so that this function solves quickly for large `b, e`s.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question right, so could you clarify what exactly do you want: do you want to get rid of the recursion, or do you just want to change the way you store data?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I understand recursion, but I want to speed this function up

Comment: The obvious optimization is to use a cache, possibly implemented as a hash map.

Comment: can't you do it this way DP[0][e] = e DP[b][0] = b and then DP[b][e] = DP[b-1][e-1] + DP[b-1][e] - DP[b][e-1]

Comment: @sukunrt Then, what is the value of DP[0][0] ??

Comment: should be 0, because the if condition when finds b = 0 return e

Comment: It should be zero once the others are calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a bottom up representation is what you want then this would do fine.

Fill up the table as MBo has shown

This can be done as:

```
for e from 0 to n:
  DP[0][e] = e
for b from 0 to n:
  DP[b][0] = b
for i from 1 to n:
   for j from 1 to n:
      DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j-1] + DP[i-1][j] - DP[i][j-1]
```

now your answer for any b,e is simply DP[b][e]

Comment: DP[0][0] once == e and then == b ??

Comment: Both the times it's 0. Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Make a table b/e and fill it cell by cell. This is DP with space and time complexity O(MaxB*MaxE).

Space complexity may be reduced with Ante's proposal in comment - store only two needed rows or columns.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 3 . . .
2 . . . . .
3 . . . . .
4 . . . . .
```

Comment: beat me by about 15 seconds :).

Comment: It is enough to store current and last row or column. Space required is O(min(MaxB,MaxE)).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this recent [blog posting](http://cpptruths.blogspot.in/2012/01/general-purpose-automatic-memoization.html) on general purpose automatic [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The author discusses various data structures, such `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` etc. Warning: uses template-heavy code.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement in O(n^2) (assuming n as max number of values for b and e ) by using a 2 dimensional array. Each current value for i,j would depend on the value at i-1,j and i-1,j-1 and i,j-1. Make sure you handle cases for i=0, j=0.

Comment: Ok, if we look at b, e they can be in 3 cases: b > e, b < e, b == e. At 3 cases, we cannot guarantee that a value exists in DP[0][0]?

Comment: You are doing this bottom up so this condition won't happen. Can you explain with an example?